# Ajax Multiple XMLHttpRequests - How to use?

Tags: ajax, ajax-request

I am new to Ajax. I wrote the following but cannot seem to figure out what's wrong with it. I am trying to invoke multiple HTTP Request calls to the web server. I looked at examples online and came up with the following.

Well, my code is not working because of some issue. Can anyone help me fix this code?

```
function getCurBid(bidID){
   var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else if (window.ActiveXobject) 
   {
       // code for IE6, IE5
       XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
   { 
       var objID = document.getElementById("curBid"+bidID); 

       XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","ajax_getBid.cfm?ida="+bidID,true);


       if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
           XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
       { 
           objID.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
       } 

       XMLHttpRequestObject.send(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you got JavaScript debugging working? Without it, you'll never figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I include console.log("??") throughout the code but not much help.

Comment: Actual debugging would have been *much* more useful - you would have spotted your particular issue (running the "result handler" code before there is a result) easily. [In Chrome, JavaScript debugging is just a click away.](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: I am using Chrome console screen. Again not much details on errors.

Comment: Most bugs don't generate any errors. Please, without further ado, insert a breakpoint in your code and experience actual JavaScript debugging. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something more like this:

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
           objID.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
    }
}
```

you need to wrap your logic in the event handler

So integrated with your script would be:

```
function getCurBid(bidID){
   var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else if (window.ActiveXobject) 
   {
       // code for IE6, IE5
       XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
   { 
       var objID = document.getElementById("curBid"+bidID); 

       XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","ajax_getBid.cfm?ida="+bidID,true);

       XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
               objID.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
           } 
       };

       XMLHttpRequestObject.send(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: so base on the following code, where would I make the call to the "ajax_getBid.cfm?ida+bidID": 

XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","ajax_getBid.cfm?ida="+bidID,true);
{ 
 if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
 XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
  objID.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
 } 
}

Comment: I noticed something wrong... your code does not work in IE compatible view. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would need more information on what "does not work" means. What is the error? You could try changing .onreadystatechange to .onload, but like i said, need more info

Comment: Your code was used as is. Basically, data (an integer) is returned from a database table via ColdFusion. ie. [  XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET","ajax_getBid.cfm?ida="+bidID,true);  ] 

Your code works fine except in IE Compatibility Mode.

There isn't much else I can give you.

I think the issue might be here: 

[   // code for IE6, IE5
XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   ]

Comment: open up the developer tools (f12) and refresh the page and run it again. See if the console logs any relevant errors